# Live Video Stream iphone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

I am new to iphone and Objective-c.
I want to show a live going match suppose football match to the users who use my app.
What do i need for live video streaming in iphone app ?

any info on this is appreciated !

Thanks

Guys please help anyone must have done this before ?

Answer (score 3):

You only need to give the URL of the movie file and the streams will automatically be setup according to the speed of your connection.

Mind you, only those videos whose resolution is within iPhone's limits will get played. Higher resolution movies will get played on Simulator but will not work on iPhone.

You need to have an object of `MPMoviePlayerController` and the rest of the code is like this:

```
-(void) play {

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://movies.apple.com/media/us/mac/getamac/2009/apple-mvp-biohazard_suit-us-20090419_480x272.mov"];


if (movieURL != nil) {
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(endPlay:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit; 
    moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
    moviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [moviePlayer play];
 }
}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;
moviePlayer = [notification object];
[moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)endPlay: (NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"end Playing");

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[actview stopAnimating];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

[moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer release];
}
```

Comment: How can u use MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification to identify playback finished? Its wrong. You have to use "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification" in latest iOS

Comment: Did you vote me down just for this? This answer is 2 years old and also if you observe carefully, "MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification" starts the playback again if paused and "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification" is used correctly.

Comment: it gives an error in
[actview stopAnimating];
anyone has any idea on that?

Comment: You can remove that line if you dont display a UIActivityView on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have video rights to the football match in question, you need an encoder which will encode live video, on the fly to the right format (mp4, h263 etc.).  The iPhone method of playing these is to have a dynamic playlist which will look through chunks of the live video to play it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Any examples of dynamic playlist in iphone with source code ?

Answer (score 1):

Heres a reference to a doc that talks about live streaming, might be of help to you http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html