# Help me to play video on iPhone App

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to do video  streaming from my iPhone application...I mean i want to play video from the web url.

So friends, pls. provide me your guidance or reference (links,tutorial )on this..

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what technology you are using to build your iPhone application.

If you are using PhoneGap and the html, css, js approach have a look at the [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp)  tag. Usage is pretty straightforward.

If you are using [Appcelerator's Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) software to build your app then you can have a look at their kitchen sink example and at their [api docs for playing video](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-object)

If your using native objective c and through all this I am assuming on demand streaming as in not a live show or something then have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491641/live-video-stream-iphone)

Hope this helps.