# Playing URL (live streaming) in iphone app

Tags: iphone, url, video-streaming, mpmovieplayer

I'm writing and app in which live stream video is playing;
The video is played from  a certain url. 
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this topic can help you: [Live Video Stream iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491641/live-video-stream-iphone)

Comment: it gives an error in [actview stopAnimating]; and i aslo what to make a play button to start the streaming when button is pressed

Comment: Well, there are many posts about streaming. It's unapparent for me what you are searching for exactly, so I have just another topic for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302383/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-http-live-streaming